# Using Case Statements As a Pivot - DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, db2, pivot

I want a list of motor carriers, with trailer equipment counts listed in separate columns. I am using case statements to categorize the different equipment types, but I'm getting multiple returns instead of seeing one return for each carrier.

I've tried ROW OVER () and get the same results.

```
SELECT C.ECP_CARRIER_IDENT_ID AS ECP_ID, C.CARRIER_NM, C.MC_NB, C.DOT_NB,
(CASE WHEN E.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_CD = 'TR' THEN E.EQUIPMENT_CT END) AS TRACTORS,
(CASE WHEN E.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_CD = 'SV' THEN E.EQUIPMENT_CT END) AS VAN_TRLS,
(CASE WHEN E.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_CD = 'FT' THEN E.EQUIPMENT_CT END) AS FLATBEDS
FROM ECP_CARRIER C
JOIN ECP_CARRIER_EQUIPMENT E ON C.ECP_CARRIER_IDENT_ID = E.ECP_CARRIER_ID
WHERE CERTIFIED_FG = 1
GROUP BY C.ECP_CARRIER_IDENT_ID, C.CARRIER_NM, C.MC_NB, C.DOT_NB,
E.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_CD, E.EQUIPMENT_CT
```

I would expect everything to be on one row, but this is the result that I'm getting

```
ECP_NB   CARRIER_NM     MC_NB    DOT_NB  TRACTORS VAN_TRLS   FLATBEDS
 1234   Bob's Trucking   606066     66    10               
 1234   Bob's Trucking   606066     66              12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation functions and fix the `group by`:

```
SELECT C.ECP_CARRIER_IDENT_ID AS ECP_ID, C.CARRIER_NM, C.MC_NB, C.DOT_NB,
       MAX(CASE WHEN E.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_CD = 'TR' THEN E.EQUIPMENT_CT END) AS TRACTORS,
       MAX(CASE WHEN E.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_CD = 'SV' THEN E.EQUIPMENT_CT END) AS VAN_TRLS,
       MAX(CASE WHEN E.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_CD = 'FT' THEN E.EQUIPMENT_CT END) AS FLATBEDS
FROM ECP_CARRIER C JOIN
     ECP_CARRIER_EQUIPMENT E
     ON C.ECP_CARRIER_IDENT_ID = E.ECP_CARRIER_ID
WHERE CERTIFIED_FG = 1
GROUP BY C.ECP_CARRIER_IDENT_ID, C.CARRIER_NM, C.MC_NB, C.DOT_NB;
```

The combination of keys in the `GROUP BY` should define each row you want in the result set.  You don't want separate rows for `E.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_CD` (for instance) so it should not be in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but I get an error message stating that "An expression starting with "EQUIPMENT_TYPE_CD" specified in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY..." and I'm not sure how to avoid that.

Comment: And I just tried adding "MAX" and it worked. I never knew that you needed to use max in the case statement. Thanks for the help, Gordon.

Comment: @BrianMinturn . . . The `CASE` *expression* is an argument to the `MAX()` function.